# Hotkey Makes Autohotkey Inactive Until Reload

Tags: autohotkey

Sorry for my bad English.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS

~^s::
KeyWait, s, U
WinWait, This is an unregistered copy ahk_class #32770,, 500
IfWinExist, This is an unregistered copy ahk_class #32770
    WinKill, This is an unregistered copy ahk_class #32770
Return
```

My problem is sometimes when i press this hotkey (ctrl + s) it makes all autohotkey script hotkeys and autohotkey's tray menu shortcuts inactive (not paused or suspended, just hotkeys don't work). Why is that? How to fix this?

Comment: Did you "Close" the #IfWinActive at the end? Under Return, add one line with `#IfWinActive`. See if this addresses your problem.

Comment: There is #IfWinActive, ahk_group ExplorerWindows after it
I posted just a part of script

Comment: Please provide some feedback on the proposed solutions and if one of the answers was helpful, then please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the white check-mark to turn it green. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provide very little information to go on... I could imagine that you might hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> e.g. to save a file while in PX_WINDOW_CLASS. If no window is activated at that time that matches your winwait, nothing will happen and AutoHotKey will sit and wait and wait...

Suggestion: shorten the timeout in WinWait, add an exit and remove superfluous lines

```
SetTitleMatchMode=2 ; Find the string "This is an unregistered copy" anywhere in your Title
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
    ~^s::
    KeyWait, s, U ; Why do you have this in there? are you hanging on your s key for more than 2 seconds?
    WinWait, This is an unregistered copy,,2 ; Wait for two seconds (or a bit longer..)
    if ErrorLevel ; If timeout of WinWait
        Return
    WinKill ; uses ID found in WinWait
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

or shorter...

```
SetTitleMatchMode=2
#IfWinActive, ahk_class PX_WINDOW_CLASS
~^s::
    WinWait, This is an unregistered copy,,2
    if not ErrorLevel
        WinKill ; uses ID found in WinWait
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Okay, I simply changed 500 to 1. I thought it was milliseconds. Well, I figured that out from your code comment. Should I mark this as answer?

Comment: @T--, Glad to see that you resolved this. If you could check my answer, that would be greatly appreciated.